# Simple Logger API using Java, Jersey, MongoDB and Json

Tags: java, mongodb, jersey

I'm learning the combo Java+Jersey+MongoDB and to do this, I'm trying to create a small Logger API. It's simple: you just POST to the server a Json file with the logged data.

Here is what I have so far.

My DBConnector:

```
public class DBConnector {
    private static DB db;
    private static MongoClient mongo = null;

    public static void init() {
        try {
            mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        } catch (final UnknownHostException e) {
            System.out.println("Erro!!!!");
        }
        db = mongo.getDB("log");
    }

    public static DB getDb() {
        return db;
    } 

    public static void close() { 
        mongo.close(); 
    }
```

My Resource:

```
@Path("/log")
public class LogResource {

    private static DBCollection LogCollection = DBConnector.getDb().getCollection("raw_data");


    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getIt() {
        return "OK you got it!"; // Just to Test

    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String addLog() {

        String json = "{'parameter1' : 'banana','parameter2' : 'orange'}"; // I still don't know how to receive the json file

        DBObject dbObject = (DBObject)JSON.parse(json);

        LogCollection.insert(dbObject);    

        return "OK";
    }
```

My Main (Not mine, actually. Comes with the Jersey project ):

```
public class Main {
    // Base URI the Grizzly HTTP server will listen on
    public static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/";


    /**
     * Starts Grizzly HTTP server exposing JAX-RS resources defined in this application.
     * @return Grizzly HTTP server.
     */
    public static HttpServer startServer() {
        // create a resource config that scans for JAX-RS resources and providers
        // in br.ufrj.cos.labia.scdp.ips_bs package
        final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().packages("br.ufrj.cos.labia.scdp.ips_bs");

        // create and start a new instance of grizzly http server
        // exposing the Jersey application at BASE_URI
        return GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), rc);
    }

    /**
     * Main method.
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final HttpServer server = startServer();
        System.out.println(String.format("Jersey app started with WADL available at "
                + "%sapplication.wadl\nHit enter to stop it...", BASE_URI));
        System.in.read();
        server.stop();



    }
}
```

The problem so far is that I'm receiving a strange `ExceptionInInitializerError` that I'm not aware how to fix.

I should point it out that I'm still a rookie in Java.

Any help?

EDIT:

```
Jersey app started with WADL available at http://localhost:8080/application.wadl
Hit enter to stop it...
Sep 16, 2015 7:14:20 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors logErrors
WARNING: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: Unknown HK2 failure detected:
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1350)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:271)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:365)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.findOrCreate(RequestScope.java:162)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:767)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:706)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:74)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:92)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:61)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:301)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:375)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler$1.run(HttpHandler.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.test.LogResource<clinit>(LogResource.java:27) // <- Copy and Paste of the line: "private static DBCollection LogCollection = DBConnector.getDb().getCollection("raw_data");"
    ... 36 more
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on com.test.LogResource
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:392)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.findOrCreate(RequestScope.java:162)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:767)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:706)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:74)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:92)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:61)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:301)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:375)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler$1.run(HttpHandler.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you provide the first dozen (or so) lines of your stacktrace?

Comment: Added. Thank you for the help, @whyceewhite

Comment: Upon further inspection, it seem s that `db = mongo.getDB("log");` is returning null. Not sure yet why.

Comment: Exactly. Glad everything got worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this `DBConnector.getDb()`. Then look at the `DBConnector`. Unless `init` is called, `db` is never initialized, so it is always null. So calling `getDb` before inializing it will return null, and calling `getCollection` on null, will cause the `NullPointerException`, which is the problem you are facing now.

The easiest fix would be to just do something like

```
public static DB getDb() {
    if (db == null) {
        init();
    }
    return db;
}
```